# Java program does not insert .csv files into mysql but no errors are thrown

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc

This will be a very long question that's far more complicated that the title suggests, so please bear with me. 
I have below a program that does three steps:

- Step 1) Checks an email server in fixed intervals for new emails with attachments and downloads the attachment to a specified directory
- Step 2) Directory is checked(I used Java's WatchService api) for file changes
- Step 3) On detection of a new file that was downloaded, proceeds to import the file's contents into a MySQL database table.

I have three classes and a main class(to execute and call the three) to handle this:

1) JobStarter (The Main class starting Steps 1) to 3) )

2) MailMonitor ---->       Details Step 1) Checks for mail and downloads attachments

3) DBConnection ---->      Small class for specifying java connection to the database

4) DirectoryChecker ---->  Details Step 2) and 3)

Now here's the problem: NO exceptions or errors are thrown. The program runs steps 1) and 2) perfectly fine but seemingly can't seem to execute step 3) even though it prints out the "successful import" statements in the terminal.

I'll illustrate it as follows:

```
New path created: uploadtest.csv
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/uploadtest.csv' INTO 
TABLE txn_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '
'  IGNORE 1 LINES(txn_amount, card_number, terminal_id)
Data import success
New path modified: uploadtest.csv
```

The output on the terminal shows that step 3) was carried out, but when i check the database table with `SELECT * FROM txn_tbl;`Nothing is actually inserted into the table.

I decided to try and isolate the Class that handles both the Directory-checking and file-importing functions and run it alone by typing out an internal main method to see if it still works, and it does. If i run it and manually paste/insert a new file into the directory, it is inserted into the database successfully. Hence my confusion. I have detailed the sourcecodes below:

**1) JobStarter code:**

```
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class JobStarter {

    public static void main(String[] agrs) throws SchedulerException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        //Define a job and tie it to our job classes

        JobDetail job=JobBuilder.newJob(MonitorMail.class).build();
        //Trigger t1=TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("SimpleTrigger").startNow().build();

        Trigger t1=TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("CronTrigger").withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(05).repeatForever()).build();
        Scheduler sc=StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

        sc.start();
        sc.scheduleJob(job, t1);
        File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test");
        MainWatch.watchDirectoryPath(dir.toPath());
    }

}
```

**2) MailMonitor:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class MailMonitor implements Job{

    private Properties getServerProperties(String protocol, String host, String port) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        //Server
        properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.host", protocol), host);
        properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.port",protocol), port);

        //SSL
        properties.setProperty(String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.class", protocol), "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty(String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.fallback", protocol), "false");
        properties.setProperty(String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.port",protocol), String.valueOf(port));

        return properties;
   }

   //Get the new Unread Mail
   public void getNewEmails(String protocol, String host,
      String port, String userName, String password) throws IOException {Properties properties = getServerProperties(protocol,host, port);
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try {
          Store store = session.getStore(protocol);
          store.connect(userName, password);

          Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
          inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
          int count = inbox.getMessageCount();
          Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(1, count);
          for (Message message : messages) {
              if (!message.getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
                  Address[] fromAddresses = message.getFrom();
                  System.out.println("...................");
                  System.out.println("\t From: "+ fromAddresses[0].toString());
                  System.out.println("\t To: "+ parseAddresses(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO)));
                  System.out.println("\t CC: "+ parseAddresses(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.CC)));
                  System.out.println("\t Subject: "+ message.getSubject());
                  System.out.println("\t Sent Date:"+ message.getSentDate().toString());

                  String contentType = message.getContentType();
                  String messageContent = "";

                  // store attachment file name, separated by comma
                  String attachFiles = "";

                  if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                      // content may contain attachments
                      Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                      int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                      for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                          MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                       if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                              // this part is attachment
                              String fileName = part.getFileName();
                              attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                              part.saveFile("/Users/User/Desktop/Test" + File.separator + fileName);
                       } 

                       else {
                           // this part may be the message content
                           messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                       }
                   }

                   if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                       attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                   }
               } 

               else if (contentType.contains("text/plain") || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                   Object content = message.getContent();
                   if (content != null) {
                       messageContent = content.toString();
                   }
               }

               message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN,true);
               System.out.println("Message:"+messageContent);

               try {
                   System.out.println(message.getContent().toString());
               } 

               catch (Exception ex) {
                   System.out.println("Error reading content!!");
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }

            }

            else {

            }// end of if-else statement

         }// end of for-loop

         System.out.println(new Date());
         inbox.close(false);
         store.close();
      } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
         System.out.println("No provider for protocol: "
            + protocol);
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MessagingException ex) {
         System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private String parseAddresses(Address[] address) {

      String listOfAddress = "";
      if ((address == null) || (address.length < 1))
         return null;
      if (!(address[0] instanceof InternetAddress))
         return null;

      for (int i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
         InternetAddress internetAddress =
            (InternetAddress) address[0];
         listOfAddress += internetAddress.getAddress()+",";
      }
      return listOfAddress;
   }

   public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException{

       MailMonitor monitor=new MailMonitor();
       try {
           monitor.getNewEmails("imap", "imap.gmail.com", "993","testserve@gmail.com", "rootpassword");
       } 

       catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }
```

**3) DB Connection**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DBConnection {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jcg?useSSL=false", "root", "password");

        return connection;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            getConnection();
        }

        catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**4) DirectoryChecker**

```
import static java.nio.file.LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.Statement;

public class DirectoryChecker {

    public static void watchDirectoryPath(Path path) {
        // Sanity check - Check if path is a folder
        try {
            Boolean isFolder = (Boolean) Files.getAttribute(path,
                    "basic:isDirectory", NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
            if (!isFolder) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path: " + path
                        + " is not a folder");
            }
        } 

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Folder does not exists
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Watching path: " + path);

        // We obtain the file system of the Path
        FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem();

        // We create the new WatchService using the new try() block
        try (WatchService service = fs.newWatchService()) {

            // We register the path to the service
            // We watch for creation events
            path.register(service, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);

            // Start the infinite polling loop
            WatchKey key = null;
            while (true) {
                key = service.take();

                // Dequeueing events
                Kind<?> kind = null;
                for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {
                    // Get the type of the event
                    kind = watchEvent.kind();
                    if (OVERFLOW == kind) {
                        continue; // loop
                    } else if (ENTRY_CREATE == kind) {
                        // A new Path was created
                        Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent)
                                .context();
                        // Output
                        System.out.println("New path created: " + newPath);

                        String newPathfinal = newPath.toString();
                        try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {


                            String file = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/" + newPathfinal;

                            String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + file + "' INTO TABLE txn_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
                                    + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  " + "IGNORE 1 LINES(txn_amount, card_number, terminal_id)";
                            System.out.println(loadQuery);
                            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                            stmt.execute(loadQuery);
                            System.out.println("Data import success");
                        } 

                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } 

                    else if (ENTRY_MODIFY == kind) {
                        // modified
                        Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent)
                                .context();
                        // Output
                        System.out.println("New path modified: " + newPath);
                    } 

                    else if (ENTRY_DELETE == kind) {
                        Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent)
                                .context();
                        System.out.println("New Path deleted: " + newPath);


                    }
                }

                if (!key.reset()) {
                    break; // loop
                }
            }

        } 

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } 

        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Any advice or help on this is really appreciated!

Comment: Can it be due to fact that your column cant handle that size of varchar2 coming from csv? and did you checked that you have csv data just before sending it to database

Comment: Yup, steps 1) and 2) are executed fine, the file gets downloaded in. And it cant be the size of the file since i used the same file in both tests: the full test where i sent it as a attachment and when i manually added it in during isolation. The manual addition led to successful insertion whereas the fulltest didnt.

Comment: The first thing that I would check is the local file.  See if you can open and read from it just before you do `LOAD DATA`.  Also, does this file have content?

Comment: When i isolated the DirectoryWatcher class(the one that does the insertion) and ran it on its own, the file gets inserted perfectly fine, thats why i'm kinda confused here. If i run the whole program instead, the same println output appears but nothing is inserted. But I see what you meant, as my code doesnt at all read the file, it just inserts. Yup, it has content.

Comment: What does the mysql error log say?

Comment: Also you're making queries with string concatenation. Are the filenames the same in your working and non-working cases? Are you sure there isn't something funky/different about the filenames?

Comment: nope, the file names are exactly the same. But to be sure, i'll run a test and get back to you on that. There are no errors at all. Everything is printed out on the IDE terminal as supposed such as "Data successfully imported" but when i check, nothing is actually inserted

Comment: Just did a isolated test on the class and a full test. Both returned the same filenames as well as directories =/

Comment: "Everything is printed out on the IDE terminal " Are you looking at the mysql error log? Because that's not going to show up in your IDE terminal. And crank up the log level.